# Is angular momentum just a crutch?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

I'm confused about angular momentum. Why is angular momentum a concept that's being described as completely different from linear momentum?

1. An object that's rotating around a center does so because it's physically constraint from moving in a straight line. If that constraint (attachment to the center) were removed, the object would move away in a straight line.
2. If I understand general relativity correctly, it replaces gravity with curved space. So earth isn't as much moving around the sun but instead moving in a straight line (albeit through curved space.)

Both cases feel to me like angular velocity and momentum are not concepts that are really different from linear velocity and momentum, but just a special case where the movement is being constraint.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your objection here. Linear momentum is constant if there is no net external force acting on a body; angular momentum (about a chosen point) is constant if there is no net external *torque* (about that point) acting on a body. In a generic scenario you could have either one, both, or neither.

Comment: the issue is conservation

Comment: I suggest learning about [Noether’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem#Basic_illustrations_and_background). Translational symmetry and rotational symmetry are entirely distinct symmetries. The former is the reason for the conservation of linear momentum; the latter is the reason for the conservation of angular momentum. Two distinct symmetries lead to two distinct and equally important conserved quantities.

Comment: Your issue about constraints is irrelevant. Rotation is not constrained translation. The “constraint” turns the motion into something completely different.

Comment: it is difficult to believe that, if you understand general relativy correctly, you should think of angular momentum “as a crutch”.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero What about Coriolis forces? What about rotating frames? I think the OP has a point. Angular momentum arises because of the choice of frame of reference.

Comment: @BuckThorn Coriolis forces are non-inertial in nature.  As to your second point, well yes rotations are about a point: there’s.no constraint here, just geometry.   I don’t see how either make a crutch.

Answer (score 14):

> Why is angular momentum a concept that's being described as completely different from linear momentum?

They are distinct concepts. Angular momentum arises from the fact that the laws of physics don’t depend on direction. Linear momentum arises from the fact that the laws of physics don’t depend on position. These are distinct symmetries and per Noether’s theorem they lead to distinct conserved quantities.